# How does server interact between client and database

Tags: mongodb, server

I just start learning back-end. Im little confused on how server interact with database.

Example: I have this document in mongodb:

```
{
   expect: 10,
   actual: 5
}
```

If I want to calculate a percent difference: actual / expect, and display the result on client-side, what should I do?

- Have client fetch data and do calculation on client-side?
- Do calculation directly in database using aggregation?

Or any other way?

Comment: Both ways are right, normally the server have more computing power, so if the task is complex or expensive maybe you should handle in the backend. In this example think there is no difference and probably do the raw division cost less than perform an aggregation.

Edit: Notice that you can fetch the data and process it before sending it to the client (without performing an aggregation)

Comment: thanks you for the insight.

Comment: Hi again, I couldnt find any article that shows how to modify or process data in server-side. Do you mind giving some example or some article relate to this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the document using query to mongodb like this (using mongoose) :

```
mongoose.findOne({id:some_id}, function(err, data){ let percent = data.actual / data.expect; })
```

then you can render the value of `percent` to the client side as well as the HTML file.

Comment: `router.get('/tasks/:id', authentication, (req, res) => {
  Task.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id
  }).then( (task) =>{
      task.aggregate(
      [
        {$group: {$divide:["actual","expect"] }}
      ]
      );
      console.log(task);
    })
});`

Comment: So what's the value of `task` that you `console.log`?

Comment: Task is the database collection,

Comment: find a task in Task collection that match the _id, then do divide operation

Comment: but it doesnt return anything, postman keeps waiting for response from server. Terminal said `(node:5968) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise 
(mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your 
own promise library instead: 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html`

Comment: I think the better approach is to get the both value (actual and expect), then divide it in the application server. That way you can debug your code easier.